# Getting Javascript object property by name

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Imagine I have an object like:

```
var obj = {
  name: {
    value: 'Sergio'
  },
  lastName: {
    value: 'Tapia'
  }
}
```

I want to create a function that grabs the `value` of a given property.

Ideally:

```
console.log(getProperty(obj, 'name'));
=> 'Sergio'

console.log(getProperty(obj, 'lastName'));
=> 'Sergio'
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with in doing so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use bracket notation to access the property on the object. Your function would be:

```
function getProperty(obj, property) {
  return obj[property].value;
}
```

I would probably name it `getProperyValue` instead.

Comment: wait, do you need `.value`? Is that even valid? Just tried it and it doesnt seem to work. But `return obj[key]` does.

Comment: @AmmarCSE did you look at his example object at the top of his question?

Comment: :) my mistake. Sorry

Comment: @AmmarCSE No worries -- I actually wrote it without `.value` at first and then realized...

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProperty(obj,property){
  return obj[property].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should help you achieve what you need.

```
function getProperty(obj, key){
  return obj[key].value;  
}
```

I believe

```
console.log(getProperty(obj, 'lastName'));
```

should return 'Tapia' rather than 'Sergio'.

Comment: There is no need for stack snippets if your code is not doing anything anyway. Makes the post easier to read.